# Iterate through JSON array in ionic displaying all data

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSuU5.png)- Image link for result of JSON data

I have JSON data in an array and I can display an individual part of the array in my HTML code. However, i am unable to display things like display  all of names in the full array (for eg I can only access `array[0]`)

ts file

```
patients: any[] = [];

this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(res => {
      this.patients = [res];
      console.log('data');
      console.log(res);
    });
```

html file

```
 // This works
 <ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients">
       Name: {{patient.patients.data[0].FirstName}}
 </ion-item>

 // Doesnt work
 <ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients"> (1) 
        Name: {{patient.patients.data.FirstName}}
 </ion-item>
```

viewpatient()

```
viewPatient() {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl + 'viewPatient.php');
  }
```

Comment: Please show the response `console.log(this.patients)`

Comment: Link for image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSuU5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewPatient()` api assign res.patients.data directly to this.patients

```
this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(res => {
      this.patients = res.patients.data;
      console.log('data');
      console.log(res);
    });
```

then on template use as below

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients">
       Name: {{patient.FirstName}}
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks very much it works! Any idea why in VSC it displays --- Property 'patients' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Can you show the viewPatient() method call ?, might you are returning type as Object or any instead of specific response type. also for patients array you can create user-defined type using interface.

Comment:  totally agree with @Ankit solution but as another option we can use async pipe

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients?.patients?.data">
       Name: {{patient.FirstName}}
</ion-item>
```

or you can assign `data` array directly in `patients`

TS:

```
patients: any[] = [];

this.viewService.viewPatient().subscribe(res => {
     this.patients = res.patients.data;
});
```

Template:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let patient of patients">
       Name: {{patient.FirstName}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Getting an error of 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

Comment: Edited, add `?` You got that error as it took some time to load the patients data

Comment: @c-mac, I have added this answer before this edited, is there any specific reason for marking this as right, and not that, because as you told my solution is worked for you.